# Reverse proxy and ws-federation adfs 401 issue

Tags: reverse-proxy, claims-based-identity, adfs, ws-federation

We have a couple of back-end web applications to which we want to provide access via the public internet.  To that end, we are setting up a reverse proxy (IIS 7.5) from our DMZ.  At the same time, we want these web applications to be claims-enabled through ADFS 2.0.

```
WEB1.MYCORP.COM/WFE1 is the other back-end web application, on our internal network
WEB1.MYCORP.COM/WFE2 is the other back-end web application, on our internal network
ADFS.MYCORP.COM is the ADFS 2.0 server, on our internal network
FSPROXY.MYCORP.COM is the ADFS 2.0 proxy server, on our DMZ
RPROXY1.MYCORP.COM is the reverse proxy for WFE1, on our DMZ
RPROXY2.MYCORP.COM is the reverse proxy for WFE2, on our DMZ
```

In keeping with the proper configuration of ADFS, our internal DNS resolves ADFS.MYCORP.COM to the actual internal server, while external DNS points ADFS.MYCORP.COM to the ADFS proxy (FSPROXY).

So, here's the scenario:

```
End user browses to RPROXY.MYCORP.COM
Reverse proxy forwards request to WEB1.MYCORP.COM/WFE1
WFE1 redirects browser to ADFS.MYCORP.COM (actually FSPROXY)
ADFS Proxy prompts for credentials and authenticates against ADFS server
Upon successful authentication, browser redirected back to web app
```

I have a couple of questions.  Do I need to configure something in the rp or the application to allow this. Also the adfs endpoint is the rp url is that an issue?

Do I need to set up something for the reverse proxy as well?  (Should I/can I) set up a claims-enabled reverse proxy in IIS?  How do I set up the reverse proxy rules to pass back the ADFS request unaltered?  Currently, when I try to access the back-end application, it fails with a 401 authentication error. If I remove the proxy and just hit the app server it works fine.

Further,
This fails:
The path is client --> rp -->app -->adfs --> rp -->app --> rp -->client machine

this works:
The path is client -->rp -->app -->adfs -->app -->rp -->client machine

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with how you enabled reverse proxy in IIS (ARR?). Something like this http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr

One choice for you is to use ADFS 2012R2 (if possible) because the proxy in that, the Web Application Proxy, handles both ADFS authentication and can handle app publishing for your claims enabled application. There are 2 ways you can publish your app to the internet. Once is pass-through which is kinda what you are trying to do. But it also allows pre-authentication support for a claims aware app. This way, you can have a different policy that decides whether the application can get pass your EDGE network before a packet goes to your internal application.

Comment: First thanks for the response. We are using ARR and IIS which is mostly working. The authentication is what is not working. Unfortunately we cannot use any other identity setup. So we are stuck using the federated identity setup. We get the token back from the IDP however not sure if it is what we want. We end up getting our own html 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

After doing lots of digging and fiddler traces I found the issue. In testing idp setup the token was different then stage env. The fiddler traces showed that the token was making it back to the app server. The issue was it also looked like the cookie dropped off for no reason. The issue was because the old dev ipd value disagreed with the stage value...naturally. Once I cleared the old token from the database everything worked.